# Dynamically bind event handler to parent of filtered element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm developing a web-app in Rails using jQuery where a lot of the processing is via AJAX POSTs of forms. I need to set up handlers for the various "ajax:" events (ajax:success, ajax:failure), which I think trigger on the `<form>` element.

Due to Rails, it's easy for me to add a class to the `<input type="submit">` elements, but not always easy to add a class to the surrounding form. Finally, because I'm using AJAX to update the page, I obviously want to bind the handlers to any newly-added forms that need them.

Is it possible, using `live()` or similar, to dynamically bind an event to the `<form>` tag which is the parent of each `<input>` tag with a given class that exists now or in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use [jQuery's global Ajax event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/),

Comment: Ah, probably a good call. Can I override them for calls that *shouldn't* use those events? I have some (to a very rough approximation, all my POSTs would want them, and all my GETs wouldn't).

Comment: Yes. You can set it in your `$.ajax` call (as `onSuccess`, `onError`, etc.).

Comment: Ah, hold on. I see that `.ajaxSend()` etc. are functions on jQuery elements, rather than absolute globals. Presumably if I want them to act on all forms, even those dynamically added later, I should register the handlers on `html` or `body`?

Comment: @Chris Yes. The most efficient way of doing this would be on `$(document.body)`.  One thing that I just read that I didn't previously realise is that the handler function is passed the AJAX settings object, so you can do `$(document.body).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings) { if (settings.type == 'GET') { ...` to answer your first question.

Answer (score 0):

sure. Use the parent() or parents() to choose it.

e.g.

```
$("input:submit").each(function(){
    $(this).parents("form").live(...);
});
```

Comment: If I understand right, that won't work because the input:submit selector will only consider those inputs that existed when the page loaded. I've got forms and inputs coming and going. Is that right?